# Continuous Bijective map

Tags: general-topology

> Which of the following statements are *false* ??
>
> **a)** There exists a continuous bijection $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$
>
> **b)** There exists a continuous map $f:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ which is injective, where $S^1$ stands for the unit circle in the plane
>
> **c)** There exists a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ which is surjective.

I think **a)** is *false* as it is similar to construct a continuous bijective map from side to square (Space-filling curve which is continuous but not bijective) not possible, but how do I prove that?

For **b**) i have no any idea

For **c)** as we know any continuous image of a compact space is compact and here $[0,1]$ is compact where $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not compact as it is not bounded

Comment: In case b, $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: @shrinit why is that relevant?

Comment: @AndresMejia I think since $f(S_1)$ is compact and it should look like a closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ and then we use inverse image of an open set will be open as f is continuous.  I think we will get contradiction.

Comment: $S^1$ is open. The whole set is open in any topology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For (b), assume $f\colon S^1\to\Bbb R$ is injective. Then $g(z):=f(z)-f(-z)$ is a continuous map $S^1\to \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ that takes positive as well as negative value. This contradicts connectedness of $S^1$.

Comment: Not sure why I found this solution so appealing, but +1 :)

Answer (score 6):

A: if there were a continuous bijection, then since $[0,1]$ is compact, and $[[0,1]^2$ is hausdorff, it would be a homeomoprhism, which it is not since any homeomorphism $h$ would restrict to $\tilde{h}:[0,1]\setminus\{.5\} \to[0,1] \times [0,1] \setminus \{h(.5)\}$, but the image of the inverse map would be disconnected, while the domain is connected.

This is just keeping track of [cut points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point)

B:  Suppose that $f:S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$. Then $f(S^1) \subset \mathbb R$ is a compact, connected component (if you know what these look like, stop here.) Otherwise, use the theorem again, so that $f(S^1)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, but then examine cut points, and deduce a contradiction.

C: Looks good to me.